# How long does it take bower to refresh a package?

Tags: bower

If I update a Github repo containing my bower package, how long will it be until bower knows about it and users of my package can download the latest version? Is there some way to trigger this?

I've changed the version in my bower.json file to a different number. I assume that's all I have to do, but I don't see it updated on bowers website or when I try to `bower install css-devices`.

[Link to the Github repo.](https://github.com/gustodev/css-devices)

Answer (score 0):

Source: http://bob.yexley.net/creating-and-maintaining-your-own-bower-package/

> Make the necessary changes to your package artifact(s) (bug fixes, new
>   features, etc, etc...whatever it might be) Update your bower.json file
>   with the new version for the package Commit your changes, tag the
>   repository and push your changes to git (don't forget to include the
>   --tags switch with your push command to your remote!) There's a couple of important things to notice here. As I mentioned previously, Bower
>   relies solely on git tags for package version information. This means
>   that in order to "release" a new "version" of your package, you have
>   only to create a new tag in your repository with the new version
>   number for the update. Its important to be sure to update the version
>   number in your bower.json file accordingly as well. With those changes
>   pushed to your package repository in git, you're good-to-go.
>
> So to summarize that: make the desired changes to your package, update
>   the version number in your bower.json file (maybe version 0.0.2 now),
>   and commit, tag and push the changes to git.

Comment: The version number in the bower.json file has been deprecated. [bower spec](https://github.com/bower/spec/blob/master/json.md#version) so that shouldn't be an issue anymore as it only relies on git tags.